# push after window location not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, push

I have an array of objects which I want to push elements in and display them on another page which I called "addtomenu.html" when a product in index.html is clicked. In other words, when the + in the right of my element is clicked, I want that product to be displayed in addtomenu.html in the new created table.
Below is my erronated method:

some of my app.js:

```
$scope.currentMenu = [
        {
          name: '',
          calorii: '',
          proteine: '',
          lipide: '',
          carbohidrati:'' ,
          fibre:  ''
        }
      ];
$scope.addItem = function (product){
      alert("OK!");
      window.location = 'addtomenu.html';
      $scope.currentMenu.push({name: product.name, calorii: product.calorii, proteine: product.proteine, lipide: product.lipide, carbohidrati: product.carbohidrati, fibre: product.fibre});
      };
```

some of addtomenu.html

```
    <tr ng-repeat="app in currentMenu">
              <td>{{ app.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ app.calorii }}</td>
              <td>{{ app.proteine }}</td>
              <td>{{ app.lipide }}</td>
              <td>{{ app.carbohidrati }}</td>
              <td>{{ app.fibre }}</td>
            </tr>
```

some of index.html

```
 <tr ng-repeat="product in produse.products | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:query">
                <td class="left">{{ product.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.calorii }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.proteine }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.lipide }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.carbohidrati }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.fibre }}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="$parent.removeItem(product)" class="buttonimage"><img src="images/remove.png"/></button></td>
                <td><button ng-click="$parent.addItem(product)" class="buttonimage"><img src="images/addtomenu.png"/></button></td>
              </tr>
```

For further code here is the full application:

https://plnkr.co/edit/QGoKptmfFrD7wjdMZSS9?p=preview

Thank you very much for support!

Comment: You should be using a router to redirect the user to another page. Your current implementation forces a refresh, and your data is going to be lost.

Comment: Isn't there an alternative method? I tried to use angularjs routes but I was always told the file containing routes script didn't load.

Comment: Well if you want to have the data accessible without using a route, you are going to need to save it somewhere, or else it wont be available to the page your going to. Your refreshing the page, so of course all of the data in memory is going to be lost.

Comment: But yes, using routes is definitely the way to go, preferably ui-router, taking advantage of states too. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I will try to use routes again then. Btw, by " save it somewhere " you mean in a/some variables?

Comment: No, any data in any variables are going to be lost when you refresh the page, you need to save the data in `local storage` or a `database` or something. But as I said, using a `router` is defintely the best way to achieve what you are trying to do, and is one of the strengths of `AngularJS` in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I will try... Thank you very much!

Comment: You said you had trouble loading the route code or something, make sure that you include the `router module` in the `app`, and make sure wherever you are defining your `routes` is being loaded as well.

Comment: Yes.. unfortunately I keep getting this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=Calorii&p1=Error%3A…ept%2FFiiPractic%2FCalculator_Calorii%2Fjs%2Fshared%2Fangular.js%3A21%3A19)

Comment: Now I don't get any error anymore but the div class content where I inserted ng-view is not displayed... basically my page is empty without it(just the header is shown)